# issue to Add a custom list view in odoo

Tags: python-3.x, xml, odoo-14

when i add my list view code in the my .xml file
this code:

```
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="test_list_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Tests">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="last_seen"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

to this file :(estate_list_views.xml)

i can not up great my module because of this error

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadi/Public/st/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/hadi/Public/st/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 316, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing /home/hadi/Public/st/odoo/oca/estate/views/estate_list_views.xml:3, near
<record id="test_list_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Tests">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="last_seen"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
```

i follow [this](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/07_basicviews.html#howto-rdtraining-07-basicviews) tutorial but that not have any description please unless introduce to me a free video tutorial for odoo

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the model name
Try this:

```
<record id="test_list_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">model.tree.view</field>
    <field name="model">your.model.name</field>
    <field name= "arch" type = "xml">
        <tree string="Tests">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="last_seen"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

See [this](http://odootechnical.com/how-to-create-a-tree-view-in-odoo-8/) for reference.